# Selecting the available previous row not working mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Well, i found this simple script online somewhere for selecting the next row and selecting the previous row.

This works. (Next page)

```
$currentid = $_GET['id'];
$nextquery= mysqli_query($conDB,"SELECT * FROM vids WHERE ID > $currentid ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1")or die (mysqli_error($conDB));
```

However, this dosent, it returns the current page id instead of the previous id.
What i want is that it gets the last available id that is on the database.

```
$prevquery= mysqli_query($conDB,"SELECT * FROM vids WHERE ID < $currentid ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT 1")or die (mysqli_error($conDB));
```

Please someone help me, i would greatly appreciate it! :D
Best regards Dániel

Comment: you got typos: change `$currrentid = $_GET=['id'];` to  `$currentid = $_GET['id'];` - plus it's bad practice what you are trying to do here. imagine your `$_GET=['id']` is the last id inserted into the database - then your query would return nothing.

Comment: Yeh sorry, i wrote the typo on here. However it shows correctly on my page, but still it not working _:/

Comment: you still didn't change your other typo: remove the "=" here: `$_GET=['id'];`

Comment: Sorry, also, a typo i typed in here wrong :P

Comment: copy-paste too strong ;)

Comment: just looked over it again. it should work besides you won't get a result for `$nextquery` if your `$currentid` equals the max id from your table. there must be some other problem with your "previous query". what errors/results is the query that "doesn't work" producing?

Comment: I have pasted my code here: http://pastebin.com/pvyvS79C the nextpage works, but the previous is stuck to 10 even if i am at id=10 it should go to id 9

Comment: and what value does your `$currentid` have in that situation? `echo` it too, please.

Comment: It have 10.
http://pastebin.com/RKQfzWCk

Comment: well, in my scripts i don't trust PHP and rather concatenate the strings myself. just another idea, try:
`$prevquery= mysqli_query($conDB,"SELECT * FROM vids WHERE ID < ".$currentid." ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1")or die (mysqli_error($conDB));`

Comment: Hmm still dosen't work :/

Comment: and you are sure there is an `ID` smaller than 10 in your table ?

Answer (score 0):

To find the largest value of the field "ID" from the "vids" table, you will want to use the following query:

```
SELECT ID FROM vids ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

To find the previous and next rows in the table, the queries you are using look correct, however there appears to be a typo in the first line calculating the $currentid:

```
$currrentid = $_GET=['id'];
```

This line should be:

```
$currrentid = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: i was thinking like you at first. then i noticed that he doesn't want to find the max id, he wants to find the next/prev id to the corresponding id.

Answer (score 0):

remove DESC for the previous query

Comment: I just tried, however now it goes to the very first ID of the table.
I want it to go to the id before the id im on.

Comment: @user3370305 yeah, that answer makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

"What i want is that it gets the last available id that is on the database."

```
`SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table_name;`
```

will give you the last record id in a table.

Next:

```
select * from table_name where ID = (select min(ID) from table_name where ID > $_GET['id'])
```

Previous:

```
select * from table_name where ID = (select max(ID) from table_name where ID < $_GET['id'])
```

Or you can optimise the query and have it all completed in one call:

```
select * from table_name where ( 
        ID = IFNULL((select min(ID) from table_name where ID > $_GET['id']),0) 
        or  ID = IFNULL((select max(ID) from table_name where ID < $_GET['id']),0)
)
```